# Menu clicking buttons with Xamarin.UITest

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, text-to-speech

I have synthesizer written in C++ with Java gui for Android.

I'm working with Visual Studio because it supports both C++ and Java. So I'd like to make some tests that would go through Android Emulator menu, click some buttons with little delay so I could see if synthesizer is working properly.

Is it possible to do such things with Xamarin.UITest?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your app the answer is yes. If you want to interact with the OS on the emulator itself the answer is probably no for reasons. One of them is that Test Cloud runs real devices.